# Why is libtiff.so.4 not recognized?

Tags: 14.04, libraries, shared-library, libtiff

I recently updated from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS. I was using [Smoldyn](http://www.smoldyn.org/), a particle-based simulation package, but since the update it doesn't work anymore. After typing

```
smoldyn
```

I get the following error message:

```
smoldyn: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, he cannot find libtiff.so.4. On the other hand, the command

```
locate libtiff.so.4
```

gives me:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.6
```

So it seems that libtiff is correctly installed. Do you have any idea what is wrong here? Why is smoldyn not running? Many thanks in advance!

---

My system:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR
- OS type: 64 bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

14.04 provides [libtiff5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtiff5) but not libtiff4 (up to saucy 13.10).

To install the 13.10 version, go to the amd64 download [page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/libtiff4/3.9.7-2ubuntu1) on launchpad and select [`libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/149178897/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb).

Now open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type in the folder where you downloaded the deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Reinstalling the old lib should solve your problem.

Comment: Link for 12.04 / precise here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libtiff4/download

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig Thanks, I've updated my links to use launchpad instead of packages.ubuntu.com. The 13.10 version is newer than the one provided in 12.04 (3.9.5).